Proving $E[Y],E[X] = \infty$ given their conditionals are Poisson distributed
Let:
$$X \mid Y = y \sim \text{Poi}(a+y)$$
$$Y \mid X = x \sim \text{Poi}(a+x)$$
for some $a >0$.
Are $E[X],E[Y] = \infty$ ?
I tried:
$$E[X] = E[E[X\mid Y]]$$
which , with the symmetry of the conditionals , gives
$$ E[X] = a + E[Y]  $$
$$ E[Y] = a + E[X]  $$
implying $a=0$ , which seems wrong...
Is there a way to get the expectations without finding the joint distribution ?

If $\mathbb{E}(X)<\infty$, then the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)$  exists and equals
$$
\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)=a+Y
$$
as the expectation of Poisson($\mu$) is $\mu$. By the law of iterated expectiations$$
\infty>\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)=\mathbb{E}(a+Y)=a+\mathbb{E}Y
$$
implying that $\mathbb{E}Y$ is finite. By the same law of iterated expectations,
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)=a+\mathbb{E}X
$$
hence $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}X+2a$ yielding a contradiction when $a\ne 0$.
Consequently, the assumption $\mathbb{E}X<\infty$ was wrong.
